# Getting "Too many slots" messages on CentOS 7 running as a domU

Tags: centos, xen, centos7

I have some CentOS 7 guests (domU) running on some CentOS 5 + Xen 3.0 hosts (dom0).

I'm seeing a lot of this in `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages`:

```
Dec 11 13:33:50 appsrv01 kernel: net eth1: Too many slots
Dec 11 13:34:50 appsrv01 kernel: net eth1: Too many slots
Dec 11 14:07:52 appsrv01 kernel: net eth0: Too many slots
Dec 11 14:07:52 appsrv01 kernel: net eth0: Too many slots

[939983.923659] net eth1: Too many slots
[940043.133026] net eth1: Too many slots
[942025.876150] net eth0: Too many slots
[942025.879094] net eth0: Too many slots
```

What could be causing this?

domU information:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

dom0 information:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.18-371.11.1.el5xen

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.10 (Final)

$ rpm -aq xen
xen-3.0.3-142.el5_9.3
```

domU config file:

```
name = "appsrv01"

kernel = "/boot/domUs/appsrv01/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64"
ramdisk = "/boot/domUs/appsrv01/initramfs-3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64.img"
root = "/dev/xvda1 ro"

vcpus = 2
maxcpus = 4
memory = 1024
maxmem = 2048

on_poweroff = "destroy"
on_reboot = "restart"
on_crash = "restart"

disk = [ "phy:/dev/sdb5,xvda1,w",
         "phy:/dev/sdb6,xvda2,w" ]

vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0','bridge=xenbr1' ]
```

Comment: Xen 3.0? CentOS 5.10? That's ancient! Did you happen to read the very first Google search result?

Comment: It might be old, but CentOS 5 with that version of Xen is supported through March 2017. Asking me if I read the first Google search result isn't helpful because we might have gotten different results.

Comment: The first result I get [explains that you really need to upgrade](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/xen/users/328514). And you say it's supported, but supported by whom? To what extent?

Comment: Supported by the CentOS project.  Thanks for providing a link this time, it's good to know the error message isn't 'fatal'.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on modern environment solved by disable of offloading on host's network card

```
ethtool -K eth0 tso off gso off
```